# Where's that margin below my footer coming from?

Tags: css, margin, footer

I have a margin below my footer in most browsers. Not in Chrome though. See [enter link description here](http://atlanticsentinel.com/)

Both `body` and my page wrapper have `margin: 0`. Wrapper is also `height: 100%`.

Here's the footer code:

`#colophon {
    clear: both;
    display: table;
    width: 960px;
    max-width: 960px;
    background: #131313;
    border-top: 3px solid #0099cc;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}`

Adding `margin: 0` there doesn't help. Shouldn't be necessary anyway. What am I missing?

Comment: Looks the same in both Firefox and Chrome to me.

Comment: If you aren't already. Use Firebug or some other web inspector. You would have found this in under a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wordpress stats tracker image is set to `visibility: hidden`, and follows your body tag.  It is this image which creates your extra footer spacing, as you can see by changing the image like so `img#wpstats { display: none; }` (don't leave it like this - see below)

I'd move that image within your main footer (ie #colophon) somewhere it won't cause a problem.  Alternatively, you could set it to `position: absolute` to remove it from the flow entirely.  You can't set it as `display: none` as the browser needs to load the image in order for your tracking to work.

Answer (score 1):

In the bottom of your code I found this

```
<img alt="" src="http://stats.wordpress.com/g.gif?host=atlanticsentinel.com&amp;rand=0.059020346471435614&amp;blog=28342037&amp;v=ext&amp;post=0&amp;ref=" id="wpstats">
```

If you remove that it works. What you should do is add `display: none` to that image in the CSS.
I saw that you have added `visibility: hidden`. When you do that it hides the image but the image will still take up room in the DOM.

Comment: That's it! I hadn't thought about that anymore. Thanks. Filip!

Answer (score 0):

the issue is caused by your latest image `img#wpstats` because its visibility property is hidden

if you set `display: none` to that image (or make it absolutely positioned adjusting negative top or left properties) you solve the problem